# PDF signature invalid after timestamp to TSA

Tags: php, pdf, digital-signature, tcpdf, pades

I've tried to sign pdf document using TCPDF in PHP.
The signature seems work properly but after i send my base64 pdf file to TSA for timestamp the document.
My Signature was invalid(in Adobe: The byte range is invalid). what is caused of the problem?

- I've used sign level2.
- I've tried to use different signed documents(already signed from others) to TSA but it work normally.
- I've used Private Key and Public Key in .PEM file.
- I've guessed that the problem was from signing process but not know further.

this is my byte range before timestamp
/ByteRange[0 1208654 1220398 12856]
this is my byte range after timestamp
/ByteRange[0 1208655 1220399 12856]

Comment: Do you mean that the TSA while timestamping changes the **ByteRange** entry of the signature already in the pdf? Then that TSA would clearly be buggy, it must not manipulate any existing bytes.

Comment: My work flow is 
1. Generate xml
2. Sign xml
3. Attach xml to PDF (for XAdES)
4. Sign PDF
5. Send file PDF to TSA for timestamp (for PAdES)
i've a bit low of know how about signatures.
do you have any method to check this? @mkl  @K J
i've tried other signed pdf (from others) to sent to TSA but it works normally
what does the probably wrong in my sign?

Comment: if the problem are from base64 transmission. i've use base64_decode() what should i fixed? @KJ

Comment: Please share an example pdf for analysis in the three stages,  i.e. the original file, that file signed by your code, and then that file timestamped.

Comment: @mkl  thank you in advance for your help these are the file that you asked.
[link](https://o365cmu-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/pannawat_n_cmu_ac_th/EtnF1rNPeq9Fuivwy35xnVUBCvzgwJCrCip0X458VcwRUg?e=Ppyiqh)

Comment: Thanks for providing the files. Most likely there is some issue in the signed revision of the PDF which results in issues while validating the changes after the signature. I'll try and look into that in more detail next week. One remark, though: You say *"this is my byte range before timestamp /ByteRange[0 1208654 1220398 12856] this is my byte range after timestamp /ByteRange[0 1208655 1220399 12856]"* but I see `/ByteRange[0 1208651 1220395 12856]` in both versions. How did you get your data?

Comment: I masked out your signature and applied an own signature and time stamp to your document, and there is no problem with that signature, even with the extra time stamp applied. I don't see a large difference between the way your signature was applied and the way mine was. The main difference is that I applied an approval signature while you applied a certification ("sign level2"). For better comparability, could you try again and share the result but apply an approval signature this time?

Comment: @mkl I have changed to approval sign but the result is still invalid on adobe. But on the web validate show that my signature was valid. no clue about how it's invalid.
this is my new upload file with unsigned, approval sign and timestamp.
[link](https://o365cmu-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/pannawat_n_cmu_ac_th/Eo2NfYHKpbZKmKnkTycD6m8B0UmX39jHJ56Hcf-h1H4c2g?e=h0coki)

This is Web Validation
[link](https://edocvalidation.digitalgov.go.th/validate)

Comment: I am analyzing the file. It is interesting, usually such issues are due to certain simple errors in the initial revision of the document that make Adobe Acrobat go mad when validating signatures with arbitrary later incremental updates. In your case, though, it's definitively not one of those standard issues. Also, some incremental updates don't cause issues with your signed document while others do. I'll continue looking. I'm sure it's something simple but apparently nothing common.

Comment: One item I see, your document has **CreationDate** and **ModDate** entries of `(D:20240111035710+00'00')` - this is incorrect, for UTC one must use `Z`. `+` and `-` expect a non-zero time difference from UTC. Could you fix that and sign again?

Comment: @mkl I've change the CreationDate and ModDate by your recommends(in UTC format). Does it's looks like this?
`/CreationDate (D:20240112064422Z) /ModDate (D:20240112064422Z)`
the result still invalid...
here's the results [link](https://o365cmu-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/pannawat_n_cmu_ac_th/Eph4kgkp5A9Ahhrt7Xq2WBoBcoSdXXM-34SBA81AtIaxyg?e=yKBWrF)

Comment: Those are valid dates. Quite a pity that that wasn't the issue... I'm looking for further issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I used your latest files from the "PAdES(UTC datetime format)" folder for analysis but the result seems to apply to your previous attempts, too.)

This is extremely weird. Trial and error showed that the first bytes after the final "%%EOF" bytes of the original, signed revision can make Adobe Acrobat believe in some invalid **ByteRange** of the signature. This is not backed by the PDF specification.

#### In detail:

Your signed (but not yet timestamped) PDF ends with the "%%EOF" bytes without a trailing end-of-line:

[image: 30 33 30 32 0A 25 25 45 4F 46]

Adobe Acrobat validation is happy with this signature.

Then the timestamping service you use adds a CRLF end-of-line before adding its own objects as incremental update to your file:

[image: 30 33 30 32 0A 25 25 45 4F 46 0D 0A 33 33 37 20]

Suddenly Adobe Acrobat calls the signature invalid because of an invalid **ByteRange**. But your signature covers the whole file (except the signature **Contents** value) with its byte range `[0 1462644 1474388 12838]`, so the Acrobat error message "The signature byte range is invalid" clearly is wrong.

Timestamping your signed file with Adobe Acrobat on the other hand did not result in the same issue.

Comparing the files timestamped by your server and by Adobe Acrobat eventually (after analyzing many other differences) showed that a seemingly minor difference has a major impact, Acrobat only appends a single LF before its incremental update objects:

[image: 30 33 30 32 0A 25 25 45 4F 46 0A 31 30 20 30 20]

After replacing the CRLF (0D 0A) after the "%%EOF" in your timestamped signed file by e.g. CR SPACE (0D 20), Adobe Acrobat suddenly again is happy with the signature (obviously not with the timestamp anymore, after all I changed the timestamped revision).

Replacing with a SPACE LF (20 0A) on the other hand does not make Acrobat happy. Apparently the LF in the second byte after "%%EOF" triggers something in Adobe Acrobat which makes it think the preceding signature is invalid.

#### What you should do:

I don't remember having had this issue before. Usually, though, the signed PDFs I deal with already come with an end-of-line marker after the "%%EOF" included in the signed byte ranges. Thus, I assume the issue only comes up in case of signatures with byte ranges that end with "%%EOF" without an EOL, only for such files Acrobat appears to react weirdly.

Consequentially, you should add an EOL after the "%%EOF" before calculating the byte ranges and signing.

If that is not possible (e.g. due to restrictions of the PDF library you use), you can also consider to append a CR SPACE (0D 20) to your signed file before forwarding it to the timestamping service.

#### Who is wrong here?

The underlying problem here is that the PDF specification is not entirely clear about whether the final "line" of the raw PDF with the "%%EOF" needs to be delimited with an EOL. I'm used to people consenting that both options, with and without an EOL, are allowed.

Adobe Acrobat here in its signature validation code seems to have a twisted idea on this topic, either due to an explicit test or due to a "repair" of the signed revision.

Comment: Amazing! it's absolutely work! After I added an EOL after my doc before timestamp.
I guessed that my PDF after signed wasn't added a new line so i send to TSA and it's might detect that my EOL was missing and add new line instead So, the previous signature would invalid.
Thank you very much for your help @mkl and KJ Cheers!